# The Functional of Real Part Integration in a Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}^*$ be the dual space, i.e., the space of bounded linear functionals of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, where the scalar field is $\mathbb{C}$. We know that if $f\in \mathcal{H}^*$, there is a unique $y\in \mathcal{H}$ such that $f(x)=\langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$.

However, how to find the corresponding $y$ of such a functional only integrating over the real part?
$$
f(x)=\int Re(x)
$$
I can't figure out how to get only the real part by the inner product.

Comment: If the scalar field is $\mathbb C$, taking the real part is not a linear transformation (why?) and the "integral" of the real part is not a linear functional.  It seems that something is missing from the problem setup, e.g. over what is the integral taken?

Comment: The integral is Lebesgue on a very general set equipped with a measure. There can be a lot, but the most obvious case is Lebesgue integration on $[0, 1]$. I saw the problem is that taking the real part is not linear since $Re(a x) \neq a Re(x)$, but it satisfies $T(ax+by)=aT(x)+bT(y)$ when $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, which deluded me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the real part from a complex number is not linear. For a linear operator $T$, it is required that $T(ax)=aT(x)$.

As for taking the real part, if the imaginary part of the coefficient is not zero, we have $aRe(x)\neq Re(ax)$ since the left-hand side can be complex, while the right-hand side is strictly real.

Hence, the integral over the real part of a function is not linear. The scalar field of the coefficients should be consistent with the function.